# Intersection of Boxes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to rigorously prove the following proposition:

Let $R$ and $Q$ be rectangular compact sets in normed space $(\mathbb{R}^2, \|\cdot \|)$ such that $R \cap Q \neq \emptyset$, then $\forall ~ y \in Q$, $\mathrm{argmin}_{y'\in R} ~{\|y-y'\|} \in R \cap Q$.

A schematic of the proposition is shown below
[image]

Moreover, is it possible to extend this proposition into $R$ and $Q$ being intersecting rectangular compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Can I further extend the proposition to metrics other than Euclidean norm $\|\cdot \|$?

Comment: Are you assuming that the sides of the rectangles are parallel or perpendicular? Otherwise it is not true. Presumably you are using the Euclidean norm?

Comment: I just realized maybe I can separate $Q$ into different regions. For Euclidean norm, I can maybe observe values of different $y \in Q$ in different regions, then characterize their corresponding $y'$? This might allow me to extend the proposition to $\mathbb{R}^n$ under Euclidean norm?

Comment: Hey, @copper.hat. That is correct. For simplicity, I am considering boxes without rotations for now. And yes, I am using Euclidean norm. But I hope to extend it to other norms, but I doubt it would be true.

Comment: One possible approach is to note that $\operatorname{proj}_{\Pi_k[a_k,b_k]} x =[ \operatorname{proj}_{[a_1,b_1]} x_1,..., \operatorname{proj}_{[a_n,b_n]} x_n ]$, where $\operatorname{proj}_{[a,b]} x  = \min(\max(x,a),b)$ and show that (under the above conditions) that for $q \in Q$ that $\operatorname{proj}_R q = \operatorname{proj}_{R \cap Q} q$.

Comment: Did the answer below address your rigour requirement?

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your answer. I was busy these days, I apologize that I didn't check this message frequently enough. I eventually use the special structure of Euclidean norm to prove the fact. Notice finding $\min_{y' \in R} \|y - y'\|$ is equivalent to minimizing $|y_j - y'_j|$ for all $j \in {1, ..., n}$. Then I separate $y\in Q$ into two cases: $y \in R$ and $y \notin R$. If you are curious, I am happy to type my proof as another answer.

Comment: I believe that is what I have done below?

Comment: I am not exactly sure why you can say $p \in [q, q']$ just from $[q, q'] \subset Q$. But the general idea is similar to mine. But I proved the fact by seperating $q \in Q$ into different cases. I will post my proof later for you to check. I could be wrong, too.

Comment: Since $q' \in R$ the closest point in $R$ to $q$ must lie in $[q,q']$ (otherwise it contradicts either minimality or convexity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a closed convex set and let $\operatorname{proj}_C x$ be the nearest point in $C$ to $x$. I will use $[x,y]$ to denote the line segment joining $x,y$, so $[x,y] = [y,x]$.

Suppose first that $Q,R \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\operatorname{proj}_R x = \min(\max( x, \min R), \max R)$. Further suppose that $q \in Q$, and let $q' \in R \cap Q$, and $p=\operatorname{proj}_R q$. Since $[q,q'] \subset Q$ we must have $p \in [q,q']$ and so $p \in R \cap Q$.

Let $R = \Pi_k [\underline{r_k},\overline{r_k}]$, and similarly for $Q$.
Since $\min_{r \in R} \|q-r\|^2 = \min_{r_k \in [\underline{r_k},\overline{r_k}]} \sum_k (q_k-r_k)^2$ we see that the problem is separable and so
$\operatorname{proj}_R q = ( \operatorname{proj}_{[\underline{r_1},\overline{r_1}]} q_1,..., \operatorname{proj}_{[\underline{r_n},\overline{r_n}]} q_n )$.

Since $q_k \in [\underline{q_k},\overline{q_k}] \cap [\underline{r_k},\overline{r_k}] $, we have $q \in R \cap Q$.